# StackOverFlowError with only two nested layouts

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-tablelayout

I am getting StackOverFlowError. I have relative layout and table layout for dynamical adding buttons. Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateButtons();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void populateButtons() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TableLayout table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableForButtons);
    for(int row=0; row<2; row++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.addView(tableRow);

        for(int col=0; col<3; col++)
        {
            Button button=new Button(this);
            tableRow.addView(button);
        }

    }

}
```

}

And here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testtablea.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableForButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Well, I found that this error is because many nested layouts. But I have only two. :(

Logcat:

```
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139): Process: com.example.testtablea, PID: 9139
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5722)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5728)
03-20 21:40:02.119: E/AndroidRuntime(9139):     at 
...
android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolv
```

Comment: is that your complete xml file

Comment: @ZaidQureshi, yes... I found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MFzuP1F-xQ

Comment: You are missing the end to your relativelayout

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi, oh somehow I have delete it from this post but I have it in my project, that's not the problem. :)

Comment: @MattGibson, i have added it.

Comment: The video tutorial also deletes the table rows in the XML so try that

Comment: Also make sure `tools:context="com.example.testtablea.MainActivity"` this is spelled correctly and points to the right context in your relative layout.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi, thank you for your advice. :)

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @ZaidQureshi. Pi Vincii gave my answer. tableRow.addView(tableRow); wast the problem. Somehow I write tableRow. add insted table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't run your code, but maybe this line make your code getting error:
`tableRow.addView(tableRow);`
`tableRow` is trying to add itself.